# How to create .pkpass file for apple wallet on serverside and get it on iOS side

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet, passkit

Here I have created `.pkpass` file following this tutorial [Manually](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1)

the above approach is static

What I want is to generate somehow the `pkpass` file on the server side and then open it from my `iPhone/iPad` device.

Comment: This question is very vague. There are lots of blog posts and web pages which explain the process of creating pkpass files server side, in lots of different languages.

Comment: if you have any guideline documents regarding how to set up on serverside, please share it

Comment: What resources have you tried already?

Comment: I am not able to figured out what to setup from my side

Comment: Follow the extensive documentation at developer.apple.com/wallet.  If you need code to copy and paste, A ruby server and SQLite example and the Objective-C source of the signpass tool are all accessible from the link above.  If you need anything more than this, you are asking in the wrong place and should come back once you have some code and a specific programming issue that you cannot solve.

Comment: i have confusion for an update pass when some change triggers an update, and my server sends a push notification. my wallet will communicate with the server and update pass or when receiving a push notification my application will retrieve new pass from server

Comment: It's explained in detail in the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1 you send an empty push payload which triggers the device to call your webservice.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking only about the apple wallet pass creating process, you need to create some server-side API (like .net core or something similar) that will return bytes array (.pkpass file) with ContentType "application/vnd.apple.pkpass".

Here it is an example.

Interface example:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<byte[]>> GetAsync()
```

Return statement example:

```
return new FileContentResult(pkpassFileFileBytes, "application/vnd.apple.pkpass");
```

Usually, it is not enough "just return .pkpass file". Usually, you will need to create a system that will manage your passes. Maybe you can just use some services with limited free wallets pass2u, passcreator, passkit, passteam.

Approx parts of Passes management system are:

1. (Must have) Create passes
2. (if needed) Delete passes
3. (if needed) Update data on passes
4. (Must have) Handler that will at least activates/deactivates pass and update it (if 2 & 3 steps are needed)